# .SQLiteException: near “,”: syntax error (code 1): , while compiling:

Tags: java, sqlite

I'm not sure why I am getting this error.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){

    String SQL_CREATE_GOAL_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE"+ GoalContract.GoalEntry.TABLE_NAME + " ("
            + GoalContract.GoalEntry._ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + GoalContract.GoalEntry.COLUMN_GOAL_NAME + "TEXT);";
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_GOAL_TABLE);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing many spaces:

```
String SQL_CREATE_GOAL_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+ GoalContract.GoalEntry.TABLE_NAME + " ("
            + GoalContract.GoalEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + GoalContract.GoalEntry.COLUMN_GOAL_NAME + " TEXT);";
```

Note the additional spaces after `'table '`, before `' Integer'` and `' TEXT'`.

It's useful to debug and view the generated `String` if you have a syntax error in generated SQL.

Comment: Thanks !.. I spent an hour trying to figure this out,tinkering etc. I am new, learning off udacity, and tried to implement this into my own project. I did not realize the space was needed.